# Trouble getting Javascript working on LAMP server

Tags: javascript, apache

I am running a LAMP server on void linux with an html frontend from my database. For some of the features I want I need to use javascript. I'm fairly new to javascript and have never had to mess with it serverside.

I have attempted to install jQuery and jspdf, I dropped them in the folder I was using for the site `/srv/www/apache/incidents` and linked them in my html. When jspdf wasn't working I decided to make a test html page which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="/incidents/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = "Hello";</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It should write "Hello" at the top of the page, but it stays blank. Is there something I am doing wrong here or have I missed something in the apache configuration? I searched all the files in `/etc/apache/` and searched the repos for anything js/apache related. Nothing shows up in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`. I know void is a little different, but up until now its been smooth sailing.

Comment: JavaScript (with the exception of Node.js which is a whole other story) runs in the browser, not the server. If you're looking for errors, open the browser's Developer Tools (press F12 in most browsers) and look at the Console (and maybe the network tool, if you're having trouble loading the script files).

Comment: P.s. the script you've written above doesn't actually require jQuery...

Comment: I know js runs in the browser, that was half of my confusion. I see the errors in the console now... though one is coming from jspdf.debug.js itself. And I know this one doesn't require jQuery, I just threw it in.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure if you knew that since you appeared to be trying to check the Apache logs for JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 0):

your javascript block is wrong

```
<script>document.getElementByID("demo".innerHTML = "Hello";</script>
```

there is a missing **)** , try like this:

```
<script>document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello";</script>
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it and it is still not working.

Comment: Sorry my bad, function name had a wrong uppercase character... try again

Comment: Ok, now that is working. Well... its not my servers fault then and I feel a bit silly for my typos.